# Can't start process in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, qprocess

I have inside the output folder a folder called `foo` with an executable `a.exe` that I would like to call. Unfortunately it isn't opening and whatever is the directory I pass to [`setWorkingDirectory`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory), I get an error output.

The code:

```
QProcess proc;
proc.setWorkingDirectory("foo"); //tried full path, warap in quotes etc..
proc.setProgram("a.exe");
proc.start();
```

Checking error:

```
qDebug() << "error = " << proc.error();
```

It outputs:

`0` value which is `QProcess::FailedToStart` (see [`QProcess::ProcessError`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#ProcessError-enum))

I want the application to start from *its* working directory and not the caller executable's working directory because of the dependencies files.

Comment: The most often reason for `QProcess::FailedToStart` is incorrect path given in `setProgram`. Did you try to specify full path to `a.exe`? I doubt that `QProcess` will search program in directory set as working.

Comment: Might be a path issue, try using absolute paths.

Comment: QProcess requires an absolute path, the working directory is independent of the executable location. See also QProcess::errorString()

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Totally missed out this. I giving the filename only because I thought it would someway cd for that then run the executable. Post it as answer so that I can accept